Windows Media Player randomly can't access files
So context: I have 4 locally stored music files. These exact same files are copied quite literally everywhere: my desktop, my 3 laptops, 2 phones, even my car. I've used them for literally 7 years, they are known to be good, working, not corrupt files. I usually actually play the music on single loop (that is, not going through the playlist, but playing back the exact same file over and over again) for upwards 30 minutes per file.
On to the problem
On my single drive Windows 11 laptop, after playing the files for quite some time. Windows Media Player would randomly be unable to access the files. Like, this current music is playing just fine for 30 minutes or even an hour, but when I go to another part of the playlist, WMP cannot play it. Not even if I close WMP and reopen it. It works if I restart Windows but will eventually happen again
The playlist does work because I can go back and forth between files normally, and notably this does NOT happen on my Windows 11 desktop, or on my phone, or the other Windows 11 laptops
The files themselves are there, like I can open the files with other music players. It's just that WMP cannot access them for some reason. And this happens randomly, it can work just fine for hours on end switching back and forth, or I can play the music for 30 minutes and boom it fails
I'm not sure what even is the problem here. What can I check to fix this?

Is the drive in question connected via an USB cable ?

Have you tried another media player, such as VLC, MPC-HC, or alternatives (https://alternativeto.net/software/vlc-media-player/)? 1. That would help decide if the issue is in Windows 11 own Media Player or elsewhere. 2. You might prefer an alternative.

@Maslie no it's an internal NVMe SSD in M.2 slot inside the laptop. DrMoishe: as a matter of fact yes. Like I said other music players can play the exact file WMP is having issues with. The players I've tried include: WMP Legacy, MPC-HC x64, and VLC. I don't really need to use WMP itself per se (I can just use Legacy) but this thing is bugging me a lot
